# My programm does not calculate right (Java)

Tags: java, calculation

I have to make a programm that calculate the probability of winning the lottery
calculated in the Austrian system (6 out of 45).

I use this formula: `45!/6!*39! = 45 *44*43*42*41*40/1*2*3*4*5*6` (because the numbers are shortened). But it isn't calculated right and the programme gives `2179827` as an answer instead of `8415060`. Can somebody help me and tell me where the mistake is?

```
package homework_1;

public class Aufgabe_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int n = 45*44*43*42*41*40;
        int m = 1*2*3*4*5*6;
        int w = n/m;

        System.out.println("Die Wahrscheinlichkeit ist: " + w);
    }

}
```

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: `45 * 44 * 43 * 42 * 41 * 40 = 5864443200 > 2147483648 = 2^31 = Integer.maxValue()`

Comment: A remark: what the program calculates is not the probability (Wahrscheinlichkeit), but the number of unique events. The probability is the reciprocal value (since this is an equal distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `45*44*43*42*41*40` it will exceed `int` limit. Use `long` to store the result

```
long n = (long)45*44*43*42*41*40;
long m = (long)1*2*3*4*5*6;
long w = n/m;
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for the help, i changed it to long but it is still giving the wrong answer? Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Did you change all the 3 variables? Because if any of them is int result will be typecast to int giving error.

Comment: Now try with `long n = 45*44*43*42*41*40*39*38;` and see what happens. You will see that `n` will hold `-1908984704`. Problem is that first value is calculated as integers and then result (still int) is assigned to long variable.

Comment: Your calculated `n` is `1569475904`, but it should be `5864443200`

Comment: @Pshemo No need to add `*39*38` to that list, it's already overflowing.

Comment: @Andreas True, added that to show it clearer with negative result.

Comment: @NadezhdaSabeva Updated the code. Added explicitly typecast to long

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as intended but 45*44*43*42*41 Exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE. (2147483647)

Use long.